# Java/Spring MVC starting page project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i'm trying to develp an mvc web application with java/spring/hibernate.

Actually, after i did all the configuration, i've only a problem.

This is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>BookStore</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And this is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Used for scan Controller Spring annotations -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="progettoPW.BookStore.backend.servlet.controller" />

    <bean name="/index" class="progettoPW.BookStore.backend.servlet.HomeServlet" />

</beans>
```

(HomeServlet redirect the application to index.jsp page)
my project works all good just for one thing: when i use the url

```
http://localhost:8080/BookStore/
```

i got the 404 error. I've to use `http://localhost:8080/BookStore/index`

i've tryed to add in the web.xml this tag

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I just want to go in my index page when i use the starting url `http://localhost:8080/BookStore/`

Some help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably add the following line in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```xml
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="redirect:/index" />
```

PS: you'll need to add the `mvc` schema to your `beans` root tag:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    ...
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        ...
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

?